# Microsoft Edge ignores text-decoration:none; for my telephone number

Tags: html, microsoft-edge, text-decorations

I just have my number on my website with an image above it acting as a link so mobile users just click it and call me. I was checking my site through a few browsers and Microsoft Edge underlines the phone number and changes the color to blue to show that it is a hyperlink. It continues to do so even after declaring the text-decoration to none.

For the sake of not broadcasting my phone number on a site that gets a lot of traffic, I do not want to provide the link to my website. I can however show the piece of code with a fake number:

```html
<div class="col-6"> <!-- NOTE: Phone -->
  <img src="images/phone.png" alt="Phone" usemap="#phone">
  <map name="phone" id="phone">
    <area shape="circle" coords="64,64,64" href="tel:5555555555" alt="Phone">
  </map>
  <h3 style="text-align:center;text-decoration:none;">555.555.5555</h3>
</div>
```

I appreciate any and all feedback as I am relatively new and self taught, so please excuse any code that may seem to be set up oddly.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. It's not supported in Edge according to caniuse.com.

https://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration

Comment: Actually, it is supported, read the foot notes. In fact, I also just tested it myself on Edge 17.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable phone number detection in IE all together using the following meta tag

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>`

or you can disable it for individual elements by using the following attribute

`x-ms-format-detection="none"`

As for removing the style like you asked in your question, you sorta can't override it with text-decoration. Although what you can do is style the link ***after*** removing the faux underline placed there by the browser.